# Python how to use POST variable as object parameter

Tags: python, django

How can I do this:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(file_path, 'rb').read().splitlines(), delimiter=";")
p = Product()

for key, row in enumerate(reader):
    f = request.POST.get('select_%s' % key) // ex. productname
    p.f = row[key] // HOW TO?, p.f should be "productname" from the variable
```

Hope you can helt me!

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What's the issue?

Comment: `key` is enumerated number, i.e. the row number, are you sure you want to do `row[key]`??

Comment: I'm confused too. Is the problem setting an attribute on p which you only know the name of at runtime? If so, try `setattr`.

Comment: Sorry that i was unclear - it was the setattr function I was after .. it worked! ;)

Comment: #avasal you was right ... the result end op like this: for row in reader:
                    p = Product()
                    for i in range(0, len(row)):

                        f = request.POST.get('select_%s' % i)
                        setattr(p, f, row[i])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setattr` to set an attribute of an object based on a name at runtime:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(file_path, 'rb').read().splitlines(), delimiter=";")
p = Product()

for key, row in enumerate(reader):
    f = request.POST.get('select_%s' % key) // ex. productname
    // p.f should be "productname" from the variable
    setattr(p, f, row[key])
```